# Vertical box plots on the same chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have two datasets

```
    Date        Daily Frequency
0   2019-01-01  1
1   2019-01-02  5
2   2019-01-03  11
3   2019-01-04  9
4   2019-01-06  1
5   2019-01-07  8
6   2019-01-08  7
7   2019-01-09  4
8   2019-01-10  5
9   2019-01-11  3
```

and

```
    Date    Daily Frequency
0   2020-01-01  1
1   2020-01-02  13
2   2020-01-03  13
3   2020-01-04  4
4   2020-01-06  1
5   2020-01-07  15
6   2020-01-08  11
7   2020-01-09  12
8   2020-01-10  11
9   2020-01-11  4
```

I would be interested in plotting vertical boxplots on the same charts but one beside the other in order to compare them.

```
import seaborn as sns

ax = sns.boxplot( y="Daily Frequency", data=df1)
ax1 = sns.boxplot( y="Daily Frequency", data=df2)
```

but it generates a box plot inside the other one.
Can you please tell me how to create two distinct box blots on the same chart?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1).boxplot()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Scott Boston.